# How to execute the ipython notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run IPython notebook but its not execute any output,it gives error like that,Error:A WebSocket connection to could not be established. You will NOT be able to run code. Check your network connection or notebook server configuration,so what can i do for that?

Comment: I found similar question, see [This][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22186057/ipython-notebook-websocket-connection-cannot-be-established

Answer (score -2):

This error means that your ipython notebook server is not running. If you are running Ubuntu or OSX, you need to go to the command-line, cd into the directory where your notebook file is, and run `ipython notebook`. This will start the local notebook webserver and you can then run code inside your notebooks. The error you are getting probably means that you accidentally killed the local webserver that lets the notebooks run.