# iPython notebook Websocket connection cannot be established

Tags: websocket, ipython, jupyter-notebook

iPython was working fine until a few hours ago when I had to do a hard shutdown because I was not able to interrupt my kernel. Now opening any notebook gives me the following error:

> "WebSocket connection to could not be established. You will NOT be able to run code. Check your network connection or notebook server configuration."

I have the latest version of Chrome and I am only trying to access local notebooks.

The Javascript console gives me this:

> Starting WebSockets: [link not allowed by StackOverflow]/737c7279-7fab-467c-9e0f-cba16233e4b5 kernel.js:143

WebSocket connection failed:  [link not allowed by StackOverflow]/737c7279-7fab-467c-9e0f-cba16233e4b5 notificationarea.js:129

Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type image/x-png: "[link not allowed by StackOverflow]/static/components/jquery-ui/themes/smoothness/images/ui-bg_glass_75_dadada_1x400.png".

(anonymous function)

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling your iPython server or creating a new profile for the server